# How to access embeded html document's children in parent html document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Simple, what I want to do is to use jquery to select text from

`<p class="oldtext">Hello world</p>`  to  `<p class="newtext"></p>`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <meta name="author" content="Ell" />

    <title>Trials</title>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

        }); //end ready
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <p class="newtext"></p>
</div>
#document
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p class="oldtext">Hello World</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

</body>
</html>
```

Please how do I do that?
Is it posible to do with JQuery or Javascript?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? This can be solved by reading jQuery's documentation and almost has all the info you need on their homepage.

Comment: Where in the parent do you want it? Parent? Are you really wanting this text from another page? `.load()` and/or just use a jQuery selector. Please be more clear. You should not have a document within another. You can have an iframe.

Comment: Is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/6tekp1xb/

Comment: It looks like an invalid HTML to begin with. Why would you do this?

Comment: actually, the new html is in an iframe. but because i am just doing an illustration, i did not bring every code.

what i want to do is to get keypress event from WYSIWYG editor which has been embeded on the page.
the editor is inside an iframe.
i want jquery to get events of the embeded document.
that is what i wanna do.

Answer (score 1):

Like this, see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5wwg1q5j/57/

```
<p class="oldtext">Hello World</p>
<p class="newtext"></p>
<script>
var str = $( ".oldtext" ).text();
$('.newtext').text(str);
</script>
```

Comment: actually, the new html is in an iframe. but because i am just doing an illustration, i did not bring every code. what i want to do is to get keypress event from WYSIWYG editor which has been embeded on the page. the editor is inside an iframe. i want jquery to get events of the embeded document. that is what i wanna do.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like:

```
$(function(){
  $('.newtext').load('yourOtherPageURL.html .oldtext', function(){
    // do stuff after load
  });
});
```

Of course, it's hard to say for sure what you want do to your unclear question. Just trying to help.

Comment: I am guessing too, I agree with one thing. I don't understand the question.

Comment: It seems like he wants to pull innerText from one element and push it into a second element.